# CustomView on Android with Scaling not working

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I am trying to create one custom view with scale functionality but its not showing anything in my below code.since it has been requested here is how I am currently scaling the bitmaps, note that I am looking for another method of scaling the entire canvas. Here is the specifics of my onDraw() method but the full method has more logic in regards to item placement and before scaling I check a boolean flag if the user has selected to scale but i figured you wouldn't want to sift through that much code so I am just putting the pertinent stuff here.

```
private final int bgColor = 8355711;
private Paint paint;
private Bitmap bgBitmap;
private float scaleFactor = 1;
private final float minScaleFactor = 0.25f, maxScaleFactor = 10f;
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;

public OratorView(Context context) {
    super(context, null, 0);
//  init(context);
}

public OratorView(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
    super(context, set, 0);
    init(context);
}

public OratorView(Context context, AttributeSet set, int defStyle) {
    super(context, set, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    if (null == scaleDetector)
        this.scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    this.paint = new Paint();
    this.paint.setColor(bgColor);
}

public void setBackground(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bgBitmap = bitmap;
    bgScaled = false;
}

private boolean bgScaled = false;

private void scaleBg() {
    if (null != bgBitmap) {
        if (bgBitmap.getWidth() > 0 && bgBitmap.getHeight() > 0) {
            float widthFactor = (float) bgBitmap.getWidth() / (float) getWidth();
            float heightFactor = (float) bgBitmap.getHeight() / (float) getHeight();
            float scale = widthFactor > heightFactor ? widthFactor : heightFactor;
            bgBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bgBitmap, (int) (bgBitmap.getWidth() / scale), (int) (bgBitmap.getHeight() / scale),
                    true);
            bgScaled = true;
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    c.save();
    c.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    // fill background with solid color
    c.drawColor(bgColor);

    if (!bgScaled) {
        scaleBg();
    }
    // draw background image if any
    if (null != bgBitmap) {
        c.drawBitmap(bgBitmap, (getWidth() - bgBitmap.getWidth()) / 2, (getHeight() - bgBitmap.getHeight()) / 2, paint);
    }
    c.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.d("OratorView", "onScale - scaleFactor=" + scaleFactor);
        if (scaleFactor >= maxScaleFactor && scaleFactor <= maxScaleFactor) {
            scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is within your ScaleListener.onScale method. This is the chunk of code I am talking about:

```
 if (scaleFactor >= maxScaleFactor && scaleFactor <= maxScaleFactor) {
          scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));
          invalidate();
 }
```

This condition will only be true if scaleFactor == maxScaleFactor. As you are only invalidating the view if this conditions is true, your view will not be redrawn as long as you are not setting the scaleFactor to 10f.

And by the way I do not understand why you are multiplying the current scale factor with the selected one. I would suggest to change this assignment to:

```
scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
```